# Approximation to a real number by rationals and derivability of power of Riemann function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**1.**
Give an irrational $x$ (We can limit it to $[0,1]$). Prove that there exists infinitely many fractions $\dfrac pq$ satisfying that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ such that
$$\left|x-\frac pq\right|\le\frac1{q^2}.$$
Furthermore, prove that the set of those $x \in \mathbb R$ such that there exist infinitely many fraction $\dfrac pq$ satisfying that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ such that
$$\left|x-\frac pq\right|\le \frac1{q^{2+ε}}\qquad ε>0$$
is a set of measure zero.

This question seems to be basically important since it indicates the speed of approximation to a real number by rationals.And I think it can use to solve the following question.

**2.**
My teacher told in class that Riemann function R(x) is not derivable in irrational point and neither square of Riemann function $R^2\left(x\right)$,while $R^3\left(x\right)$ is derivable at x= $\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$,which cannot be extracted.Furthermore,$R^n(x)$ is derivable at x=$\sqrt[n-1]{\frac{p}{q}}$.How to prove that?

Comment: See [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556320/if-x-notin-mathbb-q-then-leftx-fracpq-right-frac1q2-for-infin?rq=1)