# Is it true that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $q \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q} : |x-\frac{p}{q}|< \frac{1}{q^2}$?

Tags: approximation, real-numbers

Is there a result along the lines of :

> For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $q \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q} : |x-\frac{p}{q}|< \frac{1}{q^2}$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) what you're looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $x\notin\mathbb Q$, then $\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|\le \frac{1}{q^2}$ for infinitely many $\frac{p}{q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556320/if-x-notin-mathbb-q-then-leftx-fracpq-right-frac1q2-for-infin)

Comment: @user what have you tried? In particular, consider plugging in $q=3$; can you find an $x$ such that there is no $p$ with $|x-\frac p3|\lt \frac19$?

Comment: See [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), under irrationality measure.