# approximate irrational numbers by rational numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, real-numbers

I want to prove this below:

(1) For any irrational number $\alpha$, there exist infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{m}{n}$ such that $\left| {\alpha  - \frac{m}{n}} \right| < \frac{1}{{{n^2}}}$.

I got a hint from somewhere to prove this below:

(2) For any irrational number $\alpha$ and any positive integer $n$, there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $\left| {\alpha  - \frac{m}{k}} \right| < \frac{1}{{{kn}}}$, where $k \leq n$.

I tried to prove (2), but still can't find out how to deal with (1).

Can you help me?

Comment: $\frac{1}{kn} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$, have you proved $(2)$?

Comment: I did think of this. But it seems that we cannot assure "infinite". An extreme case is that $k=1$ always holds, then it's obvious true.

Comment: There should be finitely many $\frac{m}{k}$ by taking $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Fix $q$ a rational number. Assume there were infinitely many $n_m$ that they give $q$ as in $|\alpha - q| \leq \frac{1}{n_mk_m}$ then since $\frac{1}{n_m k_m}\rightarrow 0$ we get a contradiction since $\alpha $ is irrational.

Comment: Now since for each $n$ we get $q_n$ with the desired approximation, and since $q_n$ is obtain for a finite number of different $n$, we see there must be infinitely many different $q_n$.

Comment: I'm not very clear about your discussion. Could you please make it more precisely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56054), the following  Lemma is proven using a pigeonhole argument:

**Lemma:** Let $x$ be any real number and $N$ be a positive integer. Then there are integers $p$ and $q$ with $0\lt q\le N$ so that $\left|p−qx\right|\lt\frac1N$.

Since $q\le N$, this gives that
$$
\left|\,\frac pq-x\,\right|\le\frac1{Nq}\le\frac1{q^2}\tag{1}
$$
Since $(1)$ says
$$
N\le\frac1{\left|p−qx\right|}\tag{2}
$$
we can get a larger $p'$ and $q'$ by applying the Lemma to any $N'$ greater than
$$
\max\left\{\frac1{\left|a-bx\right|}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z},0\lt b\le q\right\}\tag{3}
$$
Thus, we can find an infinite sequence of $p$ and $q$ that satisfy $(1)$.

Comment: Your pigeonhole argument is enlightening. Could you please explain why we can get an infinite sequence of such approximations more explicitly? It still confuses me.

Comment: @gžd15: I have tried to improve the explanation of the infinitude of such approximations.

Comment: ♦: Why $\max\left\{\frac1{\left|a-bx\right|}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z},0\lt b\le q\right\}$ exists? Also why do those $\frac{p}{q}$ we get differ from each other?

Comment: @gžd15: The max exists since it is the maximum of a finite set of numbers. Note that if $x$ is irrational, for each value of $b$, there are two values of $a$ that make $\frac1{\left|a-bx\right|}\gt1$; thus, this is the max of $2q$ numbers. Applying the Lemma to an $N'$ greater than this max ensures that $q'\gt q$, since the Lemma guarantees $p'$ and $q'$ so that $\left|p'-q'x\right|\le\frac1{N'}$ and for $0\lt b\le q$, $\left|a-bx\right|\gt\frac1{N'}$.