# Given $\alpha\in \mathbb{R},$ do there exist arbitrarily large $m,k$ such that $\vert \alpha - \frac{k}{m}\vert < \frac{1}{m^2}$?

Tags: diophantine-approximation, irrationality-measure

Given $\alpha\in \mathbb{R},\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ does there exist $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m>n,\ $ and $\ k\in\mathbb{Z}, $ such that

$$ \alpha \in\left[\frac{k}{m}-\frac{1}{m^2}, \frac{k}{m} + \frac{1}{m^2} \right]\ ? $$

I suspect the answer is yes somehow, partly due to the fact that the sum of the measure (width) of all these intervals, $\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}} m\frac{2}{m^2},\ $ diverges. However, since many of the intervals overlap, the result is not so clear...

Comment: Yes, this is a classical application of pigeonhole (and afaik is the reason pigeonhole is sometimes called "Dirichlet's principle"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem

Comment: Oh, brilliant! I was not aware of that theorem. Thanks!

Comment: In the title, I think there is the impression that $k$ is constant.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Please make that an answer! - it seems quite interesting

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56054) deals with this question.