# If $x,y\in\mathbb{N},\varepsilon>0$ then are there infinitely many positive integer pairs $(n,m)$ s.t. $\vert\frac{x^n}{y^m}- 1\vert < \varepsilon?$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

> Proposition: If $x,y\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$ then for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there
> are infinitely many pairs of positive integers $(n,m)$ such that $$\frac{\left\lvert
>  y^m-x^n \right\rvert}{y^m} < \varepsilon,$$
>
> i.e. $\displaystyle\large{\frac{x^n}{y^m}} \to 1\ $ as these pairs
> $(n,m) \to (\infty,\infty).$

I think this is true, and I want to prove it. For all integers $n,$ we have

$$\frac{x^n}{y^{ {n\log_y x}}} = 1.$$

Therefore, we want to find integers $n$ such that $n\log_y x$ is, in some sense, extremely close to an integer.

This above question can also be stated as follows. If $x,y\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$ and $x>y,$ then either $\ \displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{y^{\lceil n(\log_y x)\rceil}} = 1 $ or $\ \displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{y^{\lfloor n(\log_y x)\rfloor}} = 1. $

Can we use Dirichlet's approximation theorem to prove this, or the fact that $\{ n\alpha: n\in\mathbb{N} \} $ is dense in $[0,1]$ for irrational $\ \alpha\ ?$ Or do we have to use other tools?

Comment: If you write it as $n\ln x-m\ln y \rightarrow 0$, and consider arbitrary $x,y \in \mathbb R$ doesn't this become just showing that you can approximate $\ln y / \ln x$ as a rational with arbitrary accuracy?

Comment: Certainly not if $y=1.$ You need $y>1.$

Comment: It isn't true that $x^n/y^m\to1$ as $(n,m)\to(\infty,\infty).$

Comment: $n,m$ are positive integers

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you know that? Please provide a counter-example (and prove that it is indeed a counter-example)

Comment: Hint: If $x^n/y^m< 2,$ then $x^n/y^{2m}<2/y^m.$ So it can't converge to $1.$

Comment: However, there might be sequence of numbers $(m_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ and $(n_i)_{i=1}^\infty$  such that $$x^{n_i}/y^{m_i}\to 1$$ as $i\to\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT (*It is not an answer!*).-You need the following two restrictions so that your proposition has any chance of being true:

$$(x,y)\ne(1,y)\text { with }y\ne1\\(x,y)\ne(x,1)\text { with }x\ne1$$ Clearly because if not you have respectively $$\frac{x^n}{y^m}=\frac{1}{y^m}\\\frac{x^n}{y^m}=x^n$$ and in both cases it is impossible your condition.

Note that for $(x,y)=(1,1)$ your condition is trivially verified.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggested ammendment. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\left|\,e^x-1\,\right|\le\frac{|x|}{1-|x|}\tag1
$$
if $|n\log(x)-m\log(y)|\le\frac\epsilon{1+\epsilon}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\frac{x^n}{y^m}-1\,\right|
&=\left|\,e^{n\log(x)-m\log(y)}-1\,\right|\tag{2a}\\
&\le\frac{|n\log(x)-m\log(y)|}{1-|n\log(x)-m\log(y)|}\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&\le\epsilon\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Now, using [Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56054), we can find $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$, arbitrarily large, so that
$$
|n\log(x)-m\log(y)|\le\min\left(\frac{\log(x)}m,\frac{\log(y)}n\right)\tag3
$$
which allows us to make $\epsilon$ as small as we want.